# java servlet error package doesnot exists

Tags: java, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

When I try to use `javax.servlet.http.*`; an error package does not exist is thrown. Should I want to reinstall java or it occurs due to some other problem. I'm using j2sdk 1.4.0 & Tomcat 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess servlet.jar is not on the classpath. Assuming you are on Windows, right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables, and check your CLASSPATH entry.

Comment: This is a bad advice. This needs to be solved by associating the project with a specific target runtime. See also the "possible duplicate" link on the question.

Comment: Why is this bad advice? From your phrase, "associating the project with a specific target runtime", I feel you have assumed that there is a project and an IDE involved. Also, your duplicate question link again is an IDE-related question. But, the OP has not talked about any IDE. He could very well be a guy who is new to Java and using a basic text editor. That's why I gave the most generic advice possible. Anyway, it seems to have worked for the OP, considering he has marked it as the right answer.